# Unix: How to manage files with only ! and $ characters in the name

Tags: bash, unix

I m learning the basics of unix (Bash) and have created a file with the name **--!!$$** containing the text **--!!agh!@@** like this:

```
echo --\!\!agh\!@@ > --\!\!\$\$
```

Now i m trying without success to read and delete the file like this:

```
//read
cat --\!\!\$\$
cat "--\!\!\$\$"

//delete
rm --\!\!\$\$
rm "--\!\!\$\$"
```

I have even read about **non printing characters**, and tried without success to turn non-printable characters into a printable form like below:

```
cat -v "--\!\!\$\$"
```

How can i read and delete this kind of file?

Comment: `rm -- --\!\!\$\$`. The `--` means _end of options_ and the utility will not try to interpret the hyphens as option markers anymore.

Comment: Thanks. It s working now. Thanks for the explanation. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the special characters - you're escaping them properly. But when the filename starts with `--` (or, often, even just one `-`), the command sees it as an option instead of a filename. Just use a relative pathname instead of the bare filename. For example:

```
 cat './--!!$$'
```

Not all commands will treat leading dashes that way, but most will. Some of them let you use a sentinel to indicate the end of options, like `--` by itself.  However, the shell itself will read the bare filename just fine:

```
cat <'--!!$$'
```

That doesn't pass any arguments to `cat`; the shell just reads the file and feeds it to `cat`'s standard input, so option parsing doesn't enter into it.

The dot-slash trick doesn't work for arguments that aren't filenames, but that is again command-dependent. For instance, if you want to search for a pattern that starts with a `-` using `grep`, you can use the `-e` option to tell it that the next thing is an *e*xpression and not another option:

```
$ read --help | grep -e -i
read: read [-ers] [-a array] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]
  -i text   use TEXT as the initial text for Readline
```

Comment: Sorry i was trying your answer wrong with a space after `./`. Now it s working the way you explain. I marked this answer as best. +1